# How to override angular material md breakpoints

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, angular-material2

I am trying override the angular material breakpoints,

```
$layout-breakpoint-md:     1280px !default;
```

How to override the 1280px to 1240px in the without changing angular material src?

Comment: Trying to find the same answer. Have you worked this out?